How much of One for All can Midoriya use by season 7 of the anime?
IIRC, at the begining of the anime (season 1) , Midoriya could only use 5% of the One for All quirk power. How much can he use now, by season 7?

IIRC he was able to use around 30 to 45% "At the time of writing, Midoriya can use 45 percent of One For All without breaking his bones..." (Source), with 45 being the upper limit and only in short bursts. It's unclear to me whether or not he actually gets any better because eventually in the manga

 He loses OFA

Also, technically, Deku was able to use 6% at the start, not 5. I know, small difference
but I just thought I should mention that.

that happened in the last chapter, didnt it? Either is temporary or the manga will be over

Welcome! For the sake of completeness, could you remember which chapter, or at least mention which particular events show the number 30-45%?

@Pablo I think that's unclear at the moment. Or he may have to start over from scratch. I'm not sure.
